# Attempting to disable detect_slow_plugins [Sublime Text 2] [MAC]

Tags: macos, python-3.x, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sublime Text suggested I turn off detect slow plugins as I was given an error due to a slow plugin.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comma missing after the `color_scheme` line; it should be:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Twilight.tmTheme",
    "detect_slow_plugins": false,
}
```

The error should've been fairly self explanatory...